# Как получить настройки постоянных ссылок из админки?

Tags: php, wordpress

Допустим нужно сделать редирект на определённую страницу. Но в зависимости от настроек в админ-панели постоянных ссылок, url редиректа может меняться.
Как получить эти настройки, чтобы правильно сформировать wp_redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимые настройки можно получить из БД WordPress. А, если говорить точнее, в таблице `wp_options` нужно найти запись с полем `option_name` равным   `permalink_structure`. В поле `option_value` этой записи и будет храниться то, что Вам нужно.

Обращаю Ваше внимание, что на Вашем сайте может использоваться префикс таблиц БД отличный от стандартного (`wp_`).

Comment: Совсем просто это можно сделать с помощью функции get_option ('permalink_structure');